# How to calculate/find abscissa and ordinate resolution values on ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, metadata

I am filling out FGDC Metadata for a product. Abscissa and Ordinate resolution are required fields. They are not automatically populated on Arcmap 10.1 and I can't find a way to locate (or calculate) them. Does anybody know how to come up with these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector data, the resolution is the same for abscissa and ordinate. It is the cluster tolerance. Usually 0.001 meter.

If you have a raster data, you can usually use the pixel size in X and Y. Usually they are the same, but not always. You can find them in the general properties of your image. However, note that you need to adjust these values in the (rare) case where the pixels are rotated.